# Plotting bubble plot : All the pathway term on a single axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my sample data

```
a <- dput(head(df))
structure(list(Term = c("Reactome Gene Sets", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes"), Pathway = c("R-MMU-191273", "GO:0034341", 
"GO:0050900", "GO:0046942", "GO:0001817", "GO:0048871"), VVV = c("Cholesterol biosynthesis", 
"response to interferon-gamma", "leukocyte migration", "carboxylic acid transport", 
"regulation of cytokine production", "multicellular organismal homeostasis"
), p_value = c(-11.6414922875, -9.3148301923, -6.2150336681, 
-5.9190690396, -5.8467499202, -5.767770517)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here Im trying to show the pathway and their respective pvalue

My code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Term,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value))) +
  #geom_text(data=df,label=df$Pathway) + 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3)+
  
  #scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5)) +
  labs(
    x='-log10(pvalue)', y=NULL,
    color='p_value',size='pvalue'
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face='bold'),
    axis.text = element_text(face='bold')
  )
```

The output im getting is this
[image: plot]

Is there a way where i can also get the Reactome gene set on the same axis or line as GO Biological process. My idea is to show all of them in a single line with significant pvalue showing bigger bubble.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `nudge_x` based on the `Pathway` values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Term,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value))) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3, 
                   nudge_x = ifelse(grepl('R-MMU', df$Pathway), 1, 3),
                   direction = "y") +
  
  #scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5)) +
  labs(
    x='-log10(pvalue)', y=NULL,
    color='p_value',size='pvalue'
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face='bold'),
    axis.text = element_text(face='bold')
  )
```

[image]

---

To get everything on the same X-axis :

```
df %>%
  mutate(X_value = '-log10(pvalue)') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X_value,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value))) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y=NULL, x = NULL,color='p_value',size='pvalue')
```

[image]

Comment: okay thats good suggestion but is it possible to get all the term in a single line in other words GO Biological Processes and Reactome Gene Sets all in single axis would that be possible ..right now the Reactome is like another factor ..so its being printed separately..right now if i understand they are like two factors so they are printed separately ...

Comment: gold level answer

Comment: Another customization how do i color those datapoints like something that is above -8 one color and below -8 another color to distinguish ?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question so that 1 post focuses only on one specific problem so that it is less confusing for future readers that way.

Comment: made new question i can post only once in 90 min ..