# Labelling bubble plot based on threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2

My sample data

```
a <- dput(head(df))
structure(list(Term = c("Reactome Gene Sets", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", 
"GO Biological Processes"), Pathway = c("R-MMU-191273", "GO:0034341", 
"GO:0050900", "GO:0046942", "GO:0001817", "GO:0048871"), VVV = c("Cholesterol biosynthesis", 
"response to interferon-gamma", "leukocyte migration", "carboxylic acid transport", 
"regulation of cytokine production", "multicellular organismal homeostasis"
), p_value = c(-11.6414922875, -9.3148301923, -6.2150336681, 
-5.9190690396, -5.8467499202, -5.767770517)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135651/plotting-bubble-plot-all-the-pathway-term-on-a-single-axis) given by @Ronak Shah i was able to fix my issue.

I tried to label based on threshold here is my code

```
df %>%
  mutate(X_value = 'pathway') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X_value,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value))) +
  geom_point(color = dplyr::case_when(df$p_value > -8 ~ "red", 
                                      df$p_value < -8 ~ "blue"
                                      )) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y=NULL, x = NULL,color='p_value',size='pvalue')
```

My output
[image: figure]

Here I m able to label them but the dot points are kind of overlapped with the labelled colors and the black color. How do i fill them fully with red and blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overplotting the points two times; once in black with varying sizes and once in colour with uniform sizes. You can simply combine the size mapping and the colour in a single point layer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggrepel)

df <- structure(list(
  Term = c("Reactome Gene Sets", "GO Biological Processes", 
           "GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", "GO Biological Processes", 
           "GO Biological Processes"), 
  Pathway = c("R-MMU-191273", "GO:0034341", 
              "GO:0050900", "GO:0046942", "GO:0001817", "GO:0048871"), 
  VVV = c("Cholesterol biosynthesis", 
          "response to interferon-gamma", "leukocyte migration", "carboxylic acid transport", 
          "regulation of cytokine production", "multicellular organismal homeostasis"), 
  p_value = c(-11.6414922875, -9.3148301923, -6.2150336681, 
              -5.9190690396, -5.8467499202, -5.767770517)
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  mutate(X_value = 'pathway') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X_value,y=p_value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=abs(p_value)), 
             color = dplyr::case_when(df$p_value > -8 ~ "red", 
                                      df$p_value < -8 ~ "blue")) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Pathway), size=3) +
  labs(y=NULL, x = NULL,color='p_value',size='pvalue')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>